# PHP Dynamic Marquee scroll items one at a time

Tags: javascript, marquee

I have created a function which grabs news titles from a table and scrolls the titles in a marquee.

It works as intended except for the point where it's not scrolling them one at the time but all at the same time.

Here is the code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`");

    echo '<ul>';

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {

        $title = $row['title'];


        echo '<li>';
        echo '<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">News: '.$title.'</marquee>';
        echo '</li>';

}
```

How can I get it to scroll the titles 1 at a time instead of the current All at the same time?

Comment: Do you want to put the news in different marquees or all inside one?

Comment: One marquee....scroll 1 title at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the default behaviour of a marquee element in HTML. It scrolls whatever you put into it, there's no way to influence this from the PHP side. By the way,  is **not** in the HTML standard, so your document won't be valid HTML if you use it.

Therefore, I would advise you to [search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery%20marquee) for a plug-and-play Javascript marquee control online. These usually also offer more sophisticated options.

Comment: I'm not worried about the validation.

Comment: Even so, it means it's going to behave differently across browsers. It might not even work at all in some. I haven't used `<marquee>` in 10 years, and I don't know anyone who has :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i do know a site that uses marquee with jQuery, Javascript and marquee here is the site. you can see the source by right clicking the site and brows through it. I am actually trying to find that marquee option but I am not having luck.

http://ppgmvp.com/Home.aspx